# Restore PostgreSQL data using PITR

Tags: postgresql

I am unable to restore the database to a previous time using the PITR steps mentioned on PostgreSQL website Article 23.3.3. Recovering with an On-line Backup (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup-online.html#RECOVERY-TARGET-XID)

The following are the steps I followed:

1. I made the below changes to postgresql.conf file which is located in the Data Folder:

   ```
   wal_level = archive
   archive_mode = on   
   archive_command = 'copy "%p" "C:\\archivedir\\%f"'
   ```

   I created a folder named 'archivedir' on C Drive
2. I made the below changes to recovery.conf file:

   ```
   recovery_target_time = '2014-02-05 11:45:00 CST'
   primary_conninfo = 'host=localhost port=5433 user=owner password=xxxxx'
   restore_command = 'copy "C:\\archivedir\\%f" "%p"'
   ```
3. Stopped the service of postgresql and Deleted Folder contents of `pg_xlog`
4. Re-started the service
5. `Recovery.conf` is changed to `recovery.done`
6. But I am unable to restore the database to a previous state.

I have checked multiple times by dropping tables and trying to restore the database to an earlier state. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 7):

First, **never, ever, ever delete anything from `pg_xlog`, ever.** You *will* corrupt your database. Now, on to what you've misunderstood about all this:

> I have checked multiple times by dropping tables and trying to restore the database to an earlier state. Is there anything that I am missing?

PITR doesn't work like that. It doesn't revert a running database to an older point in time.

How it works is that you set it up first, *before you need to restore*:

- Set up WAL archiving, so you record WAL to a safe location.
- **Before** you need to revert, you make a base backup. You can use `pg_start_backup()` and rsync for this, but it's easiest and safest to use `pg_basebackup()`. See the documentation for details on creating base backups. You must do this *after* setting up WAL archiving, so the archive contains all WAL from the moment the basebackup is taken onward.
- Continue to run with WAL archiving, periodically taking a new base backup to reduce the amount of old WAL you have to keep and the amount of recovery time you need. Automated tools like [pgbarman](http://pgbarman.org) help with this.

When you need to create a historical copy of the database state to recover from something, you:

- Make a copy of the base backup to writeable storage
- Set the copy up with a `recovery.conf` file that specifies an appropriate `restore_command` for fetching WAL and the `recovery_target_time` you want to replay up to.  Setting `primary_conninfo` makes no sense, since you won't be using this as a warm or hot standby streaming replica.
- Start the copy, and allow it to replay WAL until it reports that recovery is complete.
- Connect to the copy, and do whatever you need to grab the data you wish to recover out of it. You may use `pg_dump` to extract a database or parts of it, use `COPY` to extract contents of tables, etc.

If you wish to completely revert a database you can delete the datadir, replace it with the copy, and follow the procedure above to replay the copy up to a point in time.

What you *cannot* do is take an existing database and *roll it back* to some point in the past. WAL replay only goes *forward in time*. So you must *restore an old base backup* then allow it to replay WAL up to the point in time you want.